# Error: unexpected symbol en mi bucle while

Tags: r, bucles, rstudio, while

Intento usar bucle `for` para imprimir por pantalla los meses del año que tengan más de 7 caracteres utilizando en vector `month.name`, pero mi código da error y no sé por qué ¿alguien puede ayudarme?

Este es mi código

```
meses = c()
for (i in month.name){ if nchar(i)>7;
  meses=c(meses, i)}
print (mes)
```

Comment: Tienes varios errores 1) La condición del if siempre va entre paréntesis 2) el ; no debe ir 3) Imprimes mes que no existe debería ser meses en todo caso

Answer (score 0):

¡Hola!

A continuación introduzco el código que respondería a tu consulta incluyendo aclaraciones de lo que falla en tu código.

```
# Crear el vector meses en el que guardar los meses que tengan más de 7 caracteres
  meses <- c()

# Bucle en el que ir incluyendo en meses aquellos que tengan más de 7 caracteres
  for (i in month.name){
    if (nchar(i)>7){
      meses <- c(meses, i)
    }
  }
```

La condición a evaluar ha de ir entre paréntesis después del `if`, quizás por eso no te funcionaba.

Además, una vez establecida la condición, se abren llaves, dentro de las cuales se especifica qué ha de realizarse en caso de cumplirse la condición (en este caso, agregar el mes al vector `meses`).

Answer (score 0):

tip_Sang<-c("a","b","a","ab","o","a","b","a","b","ab","a","b","o","o","a,"b","ab")

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).